# SQL Query to HTML Table

Tags: html, t-sql

I have below query in T-SQL

```
DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX) SET @body = N'< table style="width:80%">'
+ N'<tr>
    < th>ErrorID< /th>
    < th>Status< /th>
    < th>Count< /th>        
    < /tr>'
+ CAST((
    SELECT
       [ErrorID] AS td
      ,[Status] AS td
      ,[Count]  AS td
FROM [Datbase].[dbo].[Table]
    FOR XML RAW('tr'), ELEMENTS
) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
+ N'< /table>'
```

Sample output:

```
<tr><th>ErrorID</th><th>Status</th>< th>Count</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>Pending</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>Pending</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>Pending</td><td>11</td></tr
```

Is it possible that there will be a conditional statement that if [Count]>10
`<td>` and the whole row will become `<td style="color:red">`? 
TIA.

Comment: You can do this in php if im understanding your question correctly.

Comment: I'm currently working with TSQL by the way. but thanks for looing into this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easier with css. Sample below.

```css
.wrapper div:nth-child(n+11) {
   color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">1</div>
    <div class="container">2</div>
    <div class="container">3</div>
    <div class="container">4</div>
    <div class="container">5</div>
    <div class="container">6</div>
    <div class="container">7</div>
    <div class="container">8</div>
    <div class="container">9</div>
    <div class="container">10</div>
    <div class="container">11</div>
    <div class="container">12</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

using the TSQL function ROW_NUMBER(), you can include in your select statement a new column populated by the ROW_NUMBER function. you now can use the new column in determining what to do when the value is greater than 10 as shown below

```
SELECT
   [ErrorID] 
  ,[Status] 
  ,[Count] ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY fieldOfChoice) AS ROWNUMBER
```

FROM [Datbase].[dbo].[Table]

However using css as shown below this post is a more elegant solution